# Npgsqlconnection not defined

Tags: ssis, npgsql

I am attempting to establish a remote connection to a PostgreSQL database utilising the Npgsql drivers to create an ADO.NET connection within Visual Basic script component of SQL Server Integration Services. I have:

1. Set the Target framework to '.NET Framework 4'
2. Added a reference to Npgsql.dll
3. Coded 'Imports Npgsql'
4. Declare variables:

> ```
> Dim PostgreSQLConnMgr As IDTSConnectionManager100
> Dim PostgreSQLConn As NpgsqlConnection
> Dim PostgreSQLCmd As NpgsqlCommand
> Dim PostgreSQLReader As NpgsqlDataReader
> ```

When I build the project I get the following errors which reference the variable declarations:

> ```
> Type 'NpgsqlConnection' is not defined.
> Type 'NpgsqlCommand' is not defined.
> Type 'NpgsqlDataReader' is not defined.
> ```

In addition warnings were generated including:

> The primary reference "Npgsql, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Npgsql, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

I suspect this warning indicates the underlying cause of the errors because Our current framework is version 4.0.30319.

I would appreciate any assistance with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen [on its nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/npgsql), Npgsql doesn't support .NET Framework 4. The minimum version of .NET Framework supported is 4.5, in addition to .NET Standard 2.0.